# How to allow only my website to show my website page

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, security

I have my website example.com, some one example-hacker.com is showing complete my website.. interesting think is that they are using cloud-flare so I can't get their server IP address to block.

Is there any way to block such website ? In Apache/Linux ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical way to stop someone else from displaying the same images and html as you have. Anything you put on your webpage can be downloaded and then uploaded on to a different webserver.

You can use a WHOIS service to figure out who owns example-hacker.com

Using that information you may, perhaps either contact them directly or give that information to your lawyer.